# Trying to Get the name of an uploaded Image

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the name of an image and save it instead of saving it as laravel default hashing.

i.e if an image name is go.jpg it should save as go.jpg instead of randomly generated numbers

Here is my controller

```
private function storeImage($news)
{
    if (request()->has('image')){
        $news->update([
            'image' => request()->image->store('uploads', 'public'),
        ]);

        $image = Image::make(public_path('storage/'. $news->image))->resize(600, 600);
        $image->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a section in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-uploads) called "_Specifying A File Name_"

Comment: $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName()

Comment: You should avoiding save it with original filename since a bad user can try to upload some malicious file and find a way to execute it. Using random filename will make it harder for attackers. Also you almost avoid filename collision.

Answer (score 0):

`getClientOriginalName` use this method.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

private function storeImage($news)
{
    if (request()->has('image')){
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $img= $file->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $news->update([
            'image' => $img,
        ]);

        $image = Image::make(public_path('storage/'. $news->image))- 
      >resize(600, 600);
      $image->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error ```Undefined variable: request```

Comment: You need to pass `Request` facade in the controller like `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and user like `private function storeImage(Request $request, $news)`

Comment: Now getting this error ```Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\NewsController::storeImage() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of App\News given, called in C:\MAMP\htdocs\main\app\Http\Controllers\NewsController.php on line 115```

Comment: @IncstarsDistribution Sorry for let response. Error describes `storeImage` function used in other function so first parameter assume 'request'.

Comment: @IncstarsDistribution Don't worry use the `Input` facade for that. I have updated my answer

Comment: @IncstarsDistribution Error occurs because resize image.

Comment: @IncstarsDistribution So shows your image `move` logic\

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method: `getClientOriginalName()`

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    return $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
} else {
    return 'no file!'
}
```

http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalName